# type promotion in C and type casting

Tags: c, operators, type-conversion, binary-operators

I have the following variables:

```
UWORD64 length;     
UWORD32 thumbnail_offset;
UWORD32 thumbnail_length;
UWORD64 sum;
```

And this is what I want to do:

```
sum = (UWORD64)(thumbnail_offset + thumbnail_length);
main_image_length = (UWORD32)(length - sum);
```

But, the first line gives me the error: *conversion to non-scalar type requested*

And the second line gives me the error: *invalid operands to binary - (have 'UWORD64' and 'UWORD64')*

I don't understand what the problem is. Shouldn't the lower types be promoted? Why is this causing an issue?

Comment: Is `UWORD64` a structure?  Your code should work fine otherwise.

Comment: Oops, yes it is a structure!

Comment: How would I proceed in this case?

Comment: Whoever defined that structure probably also defined some functions to operate on them.  If not, you'll have to write your own.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely a type def or the undefined values. I'm Using MSVC 2012 and just using Microsoft builtin types. No problems compiling.

```
unsigned __int64 length = 100;     
unsigned __int32 thumbnail_offset = 32;
unsigned __int32 thumbnail_length = 25000000;
unsigned __int64 sum = 0;
unsigned __int32 main_image_length = 0;

//And this is what I want to do:

sum = (unsigned __int64 )(thumbnail_offset + thumbnail_length);
main_image_length = (unsigned __int32)(length - sum);
```